# Custom JavaScript variable in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am trying to write a custom JavaScript variable in Google Tag Manager that will DOM scrape my company's website data so that I can send impression data to Google Analytics 4. For some reason my code is returning undefined in Google Tag Assistant. Here is the code I am using:

```
function() {
  var impr = [];
  var prod_names = document.querySelectorAll(".wsite-com-category-product-name");
  var prod_prices = document.querySelectoryAll(".wsite-com-price");
  var prod_ids = document.querySelectorAll(".wsite-com-category-product");
  
  for (i=0; i<prod_names.length; i++)
  {
    var product_name=prod_names[i].innerText;
    var product_price=prod_prices[i].innerText.replaceAll("$", '');
    var product_id=prod_ids[i].dataset.id;
    var product_position=i+1;
    var products = {
      'name': product_name,
      'price': product_price,
      'id': product_id,
      'position': product_position,
      'list': 'General Products List'
    };
    impr.push(products);
  }
  return {
    ecommerce: {
      currencyCode: "USD",
      impressions: impr
    }
  };
}
```

I've tested the querySelectors in the Console window of debug view and everything is working how it should there to return results. For some reason I cannot get the code to return the information in a dataLayer format.

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Does that function gets called by something that expects an object as return value?

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using is unsafe. Most likely scenario is you're trying to use it before the elements are ready, and it throws an exception, but you don't see it since GTM variables don't bubble exceptions to the console.

There are many scenarios of what you can do.

- You can make the code safer and get an empty impr value in your return object.
- You can turn product prices, names and ids into GTM variables and use the preview to see what event they appear on.
- You can deploy this code as a custom HTML tag rather than variable just to force the exception to show up.
- You could add a breakpoint on your event, or in your code and try it out in the console at the moment it's executed.

Many ways to debug from where you are. You should really show your debugging efforts as screenshots from the preview.